# Extra argument 'method' in call error when setting object as parameter

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am getting **Extra argument 'method' in call** error when I am trying to set object of **SessionConductBean** in Alamofire.

```
let param = [SessionConductBean(billId: self.SessionListArray[0].billId, memberId: self.SessionListArray[0].memberId)]

     Alamofire.request(URL2, method: .get, parameters: param).debugLog().responseJSON { response in

                print("Success:Session: \(response.result.isSuccess)")
                print("Result...\(String(describing: response.value))")

                if(response.result.isSuccess) {
                    if(response.value != nil){

                    }
                }
                if(response.result.isFailure){
                    print("Failure\(response.result.isFailure)")
                }


            }
```

Comment: What is  SessionConductBean? try with `let param = ["billId": self.SessionListArray[0].billId, "memberId": self.SessionListArray[0].memberId]`

Comment: It is my model class

Comment: Your `param` does not look like a valid `Prameters' object.

Answer (score 1):

This is known issue. You should check what you pass.
Quote from GitHub:

> Any time one argument is of the wrong type, the Swift interpreter here
>   believes that you're wrongly using
>   request(urlRequest:URLRequestConvertible) and therefore believes
>   there's an extra method: argument.

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1508

So be sure to pass correct url. 
Also this may well be `ParameterEncoding` issue.

Try the following:

```
Alamofire.request(URL2, method: .get,
                    parameters: param, 
                      encoding: URLEncoding.default, 
                       headers: nil)
```

Comment: I'm still getting the issue

Comment: What is your Alamofire version?

Comment: Verify your arguments. Parameters must be of type `[String:Any]`, headers (if any) are `[String:String]`. As of Alamofire 4, it works fine.

Comment: I'm using Alamofire version 3.0

Comment: So what are you waiting for then? Update! \o/

Comment: Hi! Have any success after updating to v3?